# How to declare a finite and infinite Plane in SymPy?

Tags: python, geometry, sympy

In SymPy it's possible to declare `Line` and `Segment`, but for `Plane` I couldn't find any "segment" equivalent plane class. `Plane` can be initialized

1. either with three 3D points
2. or one 3D point and a normal vector.

Does the first approach define a "segment" plane and the second the infinite one?

Comment: I think that both define an infinite plane